# Facebook Android Sdk appsecret_proof

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am getting error when I am logging on facebook.

Previously it was working fine but now i am getting this error.Please help me

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(
                                        JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {
                                   // here i am getting error App secret proof is required
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday,about,friends,education,cover,bio,first_name,hometown,inspirational_people,work,location,picture");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    //ERROR
                }
```

Comment: please show what is error?

Comment: I get response in which it says that app secret required

Comment: read out this once https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security

Comment: have you put facebook id in application